# array of bigintegers initialization in java

Tags: java

Code goes as follows.

```
BigInteger []sequencesValue = new BigInteger [sequencesNum];
sequencesValue[k]= sequencesValue[k].add(BigDecimal.valueOf(1*pow(4,i)).toBigInteger());
```

I got Null pointer exception. Any comments?

Comment: sequencesValue[k] is null

Answer (score 1):

`sequencesValue[k]` is `null`, you should initialize it first:

```
sequencesValue[k] = new BigInteger("0");
```